# SQL - How to order strings with number?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

The Customer ID is following like:

```
AMT-2
AMT-100
AMT-1
AMT-50
AMT-10
```

So I want to order the Customer ID as:

```
AMT-1
AMT-2
AMT-10
AMT-50
AMT-100
```

How to do? Please help me.

Comment: is Customer ID  column name or table name ?

Comment: does the `-100` mean -100 or is the `-` just punctuation?

Comment: Please mark the correct answer when you get the answer, so that when other users visit this answer then can easily find the answer. Till now you haven't mark any answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the prefix is always the same length, you can do this:

```
order by len(customerid), customerid
```

Comment: Is this correct way if the database is having record like `AMT-01` and `AMT-2`. I know ur solution will give correct result in his case. But, I am asking that is it correct method?

Comment: @Nimesh . . . I'm not claiming it works in all cases.  The sample data in the OP doesn't contain zero-padded numbers (and in my experience, mixed padding is quite unusual).

Answer (score 2):

this may help you ,

```
SELECT *
        FROM Customer
        ORDER BY Cast(SUBSTRING(CustomerID, 5, Len(CustomerID)) As Numeric(5,0));
```

**[fiddleExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df2d8/1/0)**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `AMT -` part from the string using `RIGHT` function and convert the rest to integer and order the result by that result.

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM customerId
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT,RIGHT(id,LEN(id)-5));
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cedf8/9)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all Customer ID's have the same prefix (E.g. AMT-),
and the suffix is numeric,
You can use SubString to get the numeric values, 
and do the sorting accordingly.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [CustomerID] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customers]
           ([CustomerID])
     VALUES
           ('AMT-2'),('AMT-100'),('AMT-1'),('AMT-50'),('AMT-10')

declare @prefix varchar(4) = 'AMT-'

SELECT  *--,cast(SUBSTRING(CustomerID,len(@prefix) + 1,len(CustomerID) - len(@prefix) + 1) as int)
FROM    Customers
order by cast(SUBSTRING(CustomerID,len(@prefix) + 1,len(CustomerID) - len(@prefix) + 1) as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `order by`

```
order by convert(int,(substring(col,charindex('-',col)+1,len(col))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is same, try this too

```
select customer_id from table
order by substring(customer_id,5,len(customer_id))*1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `CAST` the column to `XML` type and extract numbers from it and sort according to the numbers in the `customerid` column.

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM
(
SELECT 'AMT-1' customerid
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AMT-2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AMT-10'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AMT-50'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AMT-100'
)TAB
```

**QUERY**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
     SELECT  
     -- Actual customerid column
     ISNULL(PARSENAME(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),2),Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))  'customerid' ,
     -- Extract numbers from string and keep a column that sorts the numbers numerically
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),'-','.'),1) AS NUMERIC(20,0))) 'RNO' 
     FROM  
     (
           -- Converts to XML format
           SELECT CAST ('<M>' + customerid + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
           FROM #TEMP       
     ) AS A 
     CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
SELECT customerid
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY customerid,RNO
```

- **SQL FIDDLE**

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (CUSTOMER_ID nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO  @t VALUES ('AMT-2'),('AMT-100'),('AMT-1'),('AMT-50'),('AMT-10'),('AMT-98')

SELECT * from @t 
ORDER BY RIGHT(REPLICATE(N' ', 50) + CUSTOMER_ID, 50)
```

I think this will helps you

---

please mark this as answer or vote this, if it helps you

Comment: check it once this will helps you